# How do I solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

If we first split the integral into two:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}\,dx$$ 
and
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{2}}\,dx$$

Let $x = 1/u$ and $dx = -1/u^2 du$, then we have:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} -\frac{\ln(1/u)}{1+u^{2}}\,du + \int_{0}^{1} -\frac{\ln(1/u)}{1+u^{2}}\,du$$

But I'm unsure of where to go from here to prove that they cancel each other out and equals $0$. Any tips?

Comment: Where are your differentials?

Comment: After the change of variable the minus sign disappears, since the limits are inverted.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=\dfrac1y$

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=-\int_\infty^0\frac{\ln(y^{-1})}{1+y^2}dy$$

$$=\int_\infty^0\frac{\ln(y)}{1+y^2}dy$$

$$=-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(y)}{1+y^2}dy=-I$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $x=\tan y$

$\implies x=0,y=\arctan 0=0$

$x=\infty\implies y=\dfrac\pi2$

Finally use $\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$